# Is there an open architecture API or excel solution for calculating and adjusting bond pricing?

Tags: interest-rates, fixed-income, data, bond, bond-yields

Is there an open architecture API for calculating and adjusting bond prices?  I am looking to adjust bond pricing on OAS or adjusted spreads to various indices and need a tool to process large amounts of data.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [quantlib](/questions/tagged/quantlib) does that.
[QuantLib.org](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)